# Passing parameters to wpf clickonce application deployed on filestore (not web) from another application

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I have problem passing arguments from one WPF application to another.
I'm trying to start it as a new process with arguments (string) but nothing is passed.

Here is what I tried:
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData` is null.

`ApplicationDevelopment.CurrentDevelopment.ActivationUri.Query` is null

`Environment.GetCommandLineArguments` is giving me the path of the application

I'm starting the app like this:
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath, "argumentTest");

Both applications are deployed as click once, and in the second one in publish options I checked "Allow URL parameters to be passed to application"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm starting the app like this: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(filepath, "argumentTest");

`filePath` should refer to the shortcut as suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02074e01-e75e-4df4-b17a-aef91b46da00/pass-parameter-to-wpf-clickonce-window-application?forum=wpf):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs));
sb.Append("\\");
sb.Append("WpfApplicationClickOnce"); //pubslisher name
sb.Append("\\");
sb.Append("WpfApplicationClickOnce.appref-ms "); //application name
string shortcutPath = sb.ToString();

Process.Start(shortcutPath, "argumentTest");
```

You should then be able to retrieve the data using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData`.

Comment: Okey I'll try this, but is there a way for an application that isn't installed on the computer. If it's published like available online only?